# Box Shadow inside TR tag

Tags: css

I am trying to create an inset box shadow effect to a `TR` element inside a table but with no success.
I am using the following CSS:

```
tr {
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #888;
     -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px#888;
     box-shadow: inner 0 0 5px #888;
  }
```

Live demo: http://jsbin.com/urage5/edit

Is it not possible to create that effect on a `tr` element?

Comment: Is the `background-color` of the `td` set to `transparent`?

Comment: Tried changing it, still doesn't work

Comment: see my answer (below) for a partially-successful workaround.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way I've found to enable a `tr` to show a `box-shadow` is to to set a `display: block;` on the `tr` element, though it means the row will no longer match the table width:

```
tr {
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #888;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 5px #888;
    display: block;
}

td {
    padding: 0.5em; /* Just to spread things out a bit */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/prAsn/1/).

This works on both Firefox 4 and Chromium 10.x, but **fails** on Opera 11.01 (all running on Ubuntu 10.10). I don't have access to either Mac or Windows, so I can't say how Safari, or IE will handle the `display: block` on `tr` elements, or even Firefox and Chrome running on different platforms.

Comment: Unfortunately, display:block makes the elements no longer line up in columns.

Comment: This is true; unfortunately it remains the only way of which I'm aware to enable the `box-shadow`... =/

Comment: I eventually got this to work by creating a row above and below my row with a single colspan-ed cell and applying the box-shadow to that. Applying box-shadows to every single cell in the row works, but only if the blur and spread are 0px.

Comment: `display:block` breaks the functionality of the table and therefor makes no sense.

Comment: It's `box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 5px #888;`..

Answer (score 15):

To preserve a functioning table you need to style the `td`-elements rather than `tr`. The same look as styling `tr` can be achieved by using the pseudo class `:first-child` and `:last-child`. Adding slightly different values to the box-shadow will do the trick - I also added `border-radius` for a better illustration:

```
td {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
}
td:first-child {
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 2px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
}
td:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
}
```

Check out the live example: http://jsfiddle.net/KtPdt/

For some more options also check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11002210/1106393

Comment: +1 this is the safe way to go. I also did a stylus example with border on all edges here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18973828/586086

Answer (score 7):

Firefox shows shadow fine on tr tag.

Google Chrome has a bug. Vote [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=62445) to hasten Chromium developers.

Comment: It can be a choice. Because I think `box-shadow` is designed to be applicable only for blocks. My opinion is that it should be applicable to all