# Table Row Box-Shadow on Hover (Webkit)

Tags: css, webkit, css-tables

Is this possible?

My code works on Firefox. I can also get webkit to change other properties (e.g. background color, etc.) on hover, but the box shadow doesn't take effect:

```
tr:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #e06547;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #e06547;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #e06547;
    background-color: #d4d5d6;
}
```

Comment: I find styles on `tr` don't have the best support.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11002077/1106393 rather than styling `tr` you should style the `td`-element in combination with the pseudo classes `:first-child` and `:last-child`. Prepending `tr:hover` will do the trick for you:

```
tr:hover td {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
}
tr:hover td:first-child {
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 2px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 2px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 2px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
}
tr:hover td:last-child {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
}
```

**Demo 1** with inset: http://jsfiddle.net/Kk6Th/

Update:
**Demo 2** without inset (classic drop shadow): http://jsfiddle.net/2nw4t/1/
**Demo 3** without inset (*glow* effect): http://jsfiddle.net/2CSuM/

Comment: ...But, only works for `inset`. [Same fiddle without `inset` on the shadows](http://jsfiddle.net/2nw4t/)

Comment: It does work without `inset`: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2nw4t/1/) It's only the fourth property in box-shadow (formerly `-3px`) which doesn't look good. Change it to `0`...

Comment: Well, you indeed made it look right, +1! It's still a pity that I couldn't use that, because my cells are transparent (and I just wanted a "glow-like" effect). My solution: overlay a list (in this case a `<nav>` with `<a>`s) on top of the table. Which worked, because I wanted each to be a link (also solved the problem of not being able to wrap a whole `<tr>` in a link). But if I had a more complicated different situation it would have to be JS-only unfortunately.

Comment: @AvL: do you think it's possible to make this work (without inset) when also having a top & left shadow on the row? I tried changing the values of the box-shadow but could not get it to work without having some shadow spilling over the neighboring left/right cell.

Comment: @AdrienBe: Check out the edited answer: Demo 3 (works, but getting a bit hacky… Only tested on webkit)

Comment: @AvL: nice, I see that you're doing some magic inside `tr:hover td:after` to hide the spilling shadow in the inner tds, that's pretty clever even if it's a bit hacky.

Answer (score 9):

Use transform **scale(1,1)** property with box-shadow it will solve the problem.

```
tr:hover {
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ampicx/5p91xr48/

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I am facing this problem and I found a few workarounds:

1. Add shadow on all `td`.
2. Set `display: block` on `tr`.
3. Use properly styled `td:first-child:before`.
4. Add shadow to all `td` and cover parts that we don't need.

You can check them on this jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/maskl/cxscmvpr/3/

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this post while dealing with a similar problem, recently. I think I have found another approach using the `display: flex;` along with `position: relative;` properties on your `tr` element in CSS  with much less markup (little `td` styling and less psuedo styling):

### Setup `tr` as flexbox

```
tr {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center; /* Vertically aligns td's inside the tr */        
}
```

This sets up the TR as a flexbox which allows it to be affected by `z-index` without breaking it's position in the DOM. All you need to, then, is adjust the `z-index` of the `tr:hover` pseudo element and add your `background-color` and `box-shadow` effects:

### Setup `:hover` Effects

```
tr:hover {
    z-index: 1 /* or higher if necessary */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #e06547;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #e06547;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #e06547;
    background-color: #d4d5d6;
}
```

You may need to adjust the size and position of `td` elements inside of the `tr` flexbox using the `align-items` since we are no longer using the tr's default `display: table-row` property. You would center your `td` elements vertically using thr `align-items: center;` property (see above). Then you set your td width

```
td {
    width: 10em;
}
```

See the working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/t68b9cwd/6/

This solution is fairly universal, with modern browsers handling this without prefixes but their may be instances with older browsers that you may need to perform workarounds (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Backwards_Compatibility_of_Flexbox) and is similar to how Google styles the rows in Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and I put some minor border-radius on it, and it works.

```
border-radius: 1px;
```

Depending on the look you are trying to achieve, it might be a hack you can use.

Comment: Tested and not working. Besides, border-radius has no effect whatsoever on table rows, even if you wanted one (at least on Webkit, which is the issue at hand).

Answer (score 0):

AvL's solution is very good, thank you for the tip. Though if like me you want the `box-shadow (inset)` in the whole <kbd>tr</kbd>, not just a side, this code should help you :

```
tr:hover td {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset, 0 -4px 2px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
}
tr:hover td:first-child {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 2px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset, 4px -4px 2px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
}
tr:hover td:last-child {
    -webkit-box-shadow: -4px 4px 2px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset, -4px -4px 2px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Add this

```
tr {
    display: block;
}
```

For some reason Webkit needs to explicitly know that the element is a block element to display a box-shadow.

Comment: This works BUT.. the table row (naturally) starts acting like a regular block element. So the auto-spacing, and colspan, etc. gets lost. Would've been nice if we could have our cake and eat it too.