# Table Row Box-Shadow Glow on Hover (Webkit/Chrome)

Tags: css, hover, css-tables

In the Chrome browser it's not possible to style a table row with `box-shadow` on hover. It does work in Chrome when you assign the box-shadow to `td` with pseudo classes `:first-child` and `:last-child`. (reference: [Table Row Box-Shadow on Hover (Webkit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972525/table-row-box-shadow-on-hover-webkit) )

I'm trying to use `box-shadow` for a glow effect on a table row. The problem is that without h-shadow or v-shadow values the `box-shadow` also appears in the middle of the table row.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2nw4t/25/

```
tr:hover td {
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

A solution for this problem would be a overlay `div` positioned with jQuery, but i'm wondering if it can be done with CSS only.

Comment: It seems to work to me

Comment: Yes Cody it works, but not like I want it to. As you can see in the fiddle there's also box-shadow around the 'name' and 'phone' td, and that's not what I want. I want the box-shadow to be only displayed outside the table row, not inside.