# box-shadow on tr's

Tags: html, css

I am having problems putting a `box-shadow` on `tr`s inside a table. The problem is that the `box-shadow` doesn't show up at all unless the `display` of all the `tr`s of the table is set to `block` (a 'fix' I found here: [Box Shadow inside TR tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605308/box-shadow-inside-tr-tag)). However, when the `display` of `tr`s is set to `block`, it makes the table cells no longer line up, crowding all to the left.

Here's a fiddle demonstrating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/jFdEY/

You can try changing it to apply to all `tr`s  but that causes another problem (in the second picture below).

---

Here's some pictures:

The one without `display: block` on all the `tr`s (table displays properly but `box-shadow` doesn't work)
[image]

The one *with* `display: block` on all the `tr`s (`box-shadow` shows up but the table layout is broken)
[image]

So, is there a way around this?

Comment: Please post all the relevant HTML and CSS to demonstrate what's going on here.  I'm sure there's a way to line the table cells up as you desire, but the solution depends on the context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Many of the elements used within tables are neither `block` nor `inline` elements."

For this reason setting all TR to `block` is most likely breaking the natural table behavior.

EDIT: I was able to create a solution similar to your desired effect however it requires that the columns have fixed width.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jFdEY/2/

Technically this isn't a table anymore though, just appears as such.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this doesn't work either and makes the `tr`s that this is applied to appear in the normal place but every `tr` that doesn't have this rule has it's left start where the rights of the ones that do end. I will post a code example of what demonstrates the problem I'm having.

Comment: @Seth please see edits. It's not ideal, but I don't think there is an ideal solution here.

Comment: thanks and +1, but I'm not going to mark this q as answered in case someone stumbles accross it and has a complete proper fix.