# How to put a bit of space between table footer/header and body content?

Tags: html, css, html-table, footer

I want to put a bit of space between HTML table header and footer, and my body content. I though margin-top and margin-bottom would do it, but it does not. Yet the font-weight: bold; directive is taken into account.

My HTML:

```
<table id="myTbl">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>My Table Header</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>  
   <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>My Body Content</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
   <tfoot>
     <tr>
       <th>My Table Footer</th>
     </tr>
   </tfoot>  
</table>
```

My CSS:

```
#myTbl {
    font-weight: normal;
}

#myTbl thead {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#myTbl tfoot {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

The JSFiddle is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nCe3k/1/). I am using Chrome.

Comment: Margin doesn't apply to internal `<table>` elements - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258754/spacing-between-thead-and-tbody

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try using padding on the th elements.

```
#myTbl {
    font-weight: normal;
}

#myTbl thead tr th{
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#myTbl tfoot tr th{
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nCe3k/9/

Answer (score 10):

Use [`border-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing) property:

```
#myTbl {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 5px;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/nCe3k/7/)**

**[`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) property:**

> Applies to all elements except elements with `table` display types other than `table-caption`, `table` and `inline-table`.

I explained **Why** probably there's no other way to achieve this, [lately on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18346159/1725764).

### Update:

> Your solution adds spacing between all cells.

Then you need to change the `display` type to be able to use `margin` property:

```
#myTbl thead {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#myTbl tfoot {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/nCe3k/12/)**

Comment: Your solution adds spacing between all cells. This is what I was looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/nCe3k/10/

Comment: Ok, but when there are multiple columns, it does not work anymore:     http://jsfiddle.net/nCe3k/13/

Comment: @JVerstry, Yes in that case it fails. But note that `padding` is useful only when you don't have any `background` or `border` in `thead` and `tfoot` cells.

Comment: Well done, your last solution still works quite well in 2022 :-) I wasn't aware that `display: table;` existed (as well as a dozen other table-related display settings) — and that it has been supported by major browsers for so long! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Here is my solution:

```
.common-table-body:before {
  line-height:1.5em;
  content:".";
  color:white;
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can add an empty row between the head and body/body and footer -

```
     ...</thead>
     <tr height="10px"></tr>
     <tbody>...
```