# How to add space between header and body table in Angular Material 13?

Tags: html, css, angular, html-table

How can I add space(margin) between header and body in a angular material table?

I tried at first with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258754/spacing-between-thead-and-tbody) but it didn't work.

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-anphrw?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: I don't know if it's possible but it's not the way to go: https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles. Maybe implement your own table-component that has the features you need.

Comment: When you refer to header, are you referring to the bolded elements in your code? (ex. driver ID, Speed, etc..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258754/spacing-between-thead-and-tbody) can work.

You must add modifiers in order to apply the style to material elements such as `:host` and `::ng-deep`.

Then don't forget to play with the `line-height` attribute to modify the space between header and body.

This can be controversial because of supposed future deprecation and similarity with `!important` but it works well, and while you know what you do, it's not a bad thing to use them in my opinion.

I have [forked](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-djltht) your stackblitz project with the modifiers.

And [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/) is a course for those modifiers, to understand how and when to use them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your css in **style.css**

```
tbody:before {
  content: '\200C';
  display: block;
  line-height: 5rem;
  text-indent: -99999px;
}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this style:

```
th {
    padding-bottom: 50px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an height to your thead like this in your css :

```css
thead {
  height: 120px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table thead {
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
}
```