# Highlighting a table row with something other than background color

Tags: css, border, html-table, highlight, outline

I'm trying to find a reasonable CSS style for highlighting a particular table row (i.e. on a click selection) that doesn't involve changing the background color, because the row colors already serve a purpose in my application.

This probably means making the border stand out or doing something to the background that doesn't change its color. I've tried the following

- `border: 2px ...` with `margin: -2px` or something like that. However, it doesn't display too well, especially when the table is scrolling, and doesn't offer a good highlight without a super thick border. Browser support of borders on `<tr>` elements also isn't great.
- `outline: 3px ...` only seems to display on the top and bottom when the div containing the table is scrollable.
- `box-shadow: 5px 5px ... color inset` [doesn't seem to display properly without messing up the table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605308/586086).

Does anyone have any good CSS suggestions for how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that you can do this using css selectors on the `<td>` elements, being careful with the two ends. For example, I created the following stylus code, which could be turned into a mixin. The trick is to use a negative `spread` value to get rid of the borders that would show up on any side you don't want, while using the `blur` and horizontal/vertical values to get the nice effect on the sides you do want. The `blur` must be at most half the `spread`.

```
shadow-color = rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
shadow = 15px
-shadow = - shadow
blur = 5px
spread = -10px

tr.selected > td
    box-shadow:
        0 shadow blur spread shadow-color inset,
        0 -shadow blur spread shadow-color inset

// Since we have to, make the top left and bottom right corners the dark overlapping ones
tr.selected > td:first-child
    box-shadow:
        shadow -shadow blur spread shadow-color inset,
        0 shadow blur spread shadow-color inset

tr.selected > td:last-child
    box-shadow:
        0 -shadow blur spread shadow-color inset,
        -shadow shadow blur spread shadow-color inset
```

This creates a shadow border like the following, allowing any background color to still show up:

[image]

However, **it's not possible to do this with normal (non-inset) box-shadows** because they will show up in between the table cells.

Answer (score 0):

Change the HTML to:

```
<td style="padding:20px;">
   <div class="tdContentWrapper">
    <div>SomeStuff</div>
    <div>SomeMoreStuff</div>
   </div>
 </td>
```

Change the CSS to:

```
#MyTable .tdContentWrapper:hover{
  background: black;
```

}

Comment: I want to highlight the entire row, not a single cell.

Answer (score 0):

How about increasing the padding and/or line-height with a subtle increase in font-size?

The row gets highlighted explicitly enough without affecting the visual styling of its corresponding peers; I might even tweak the color, if it's possible, depending on the alternating backgrounds.