# Internet Explorer and Chrome: table-hover not displayed properly

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, hover

For better visual experience i use a CSS style on a `<tr>` when hovering over it.

to see the complete design: http://jsfiddle.net/rDjE3/1/

i used:

`.table_test tr:hover {
    outline: none;
    border-color: #29EC24;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #29EC24;
}`

this works fine in firefox.

but in Internet Explorer the hover gets displayed not complete (just between the `<td>`) and in Google Chrome completely nothing is displayed.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it seems it's a official bug for Chrome. As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605308/box-shadow-inside-tr-tag/11002077) the only way to do this is by setting `'display: block'` on the `<tr>` element, which requires you to fix the positioning afterwards.

Also, box-shadow requires you to use the `-webkit-` prefix for Chrome. You can see a 'working' and malformed example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rDjE3/2/). But you'll have to set the width of the table cells by yourself.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rDjE3/3/ take a look what happens now when you add a new `<tr>`

Comment: they overlap, and one stays on top of the others. I added z-index to the trstyle class. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/rDjE3/9/