# box-shadow on display:table-row-group failing in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css

`box-shadow` is not working in Chrome.

I have a table layout in which I have to use `display` property as `table-row-group`.
I am trying to put `box-shadow` in tbody and it's failing. 
Please see it here - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w4p5L/1/).

It's working perfectly fine in FF but not in Chrome. I looked on other questions/suggestions and it looks like we can do it in `display: block` property.

Any workaround for `display: table-row-group`?

Comment: Based on [other similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5605612/976897) on StackOverflow, I think `display:block` seems to be your only option, just like you mentioned. Seems like there is [a bug issued](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=62445) on Chromium bug tracker to fix this.

Comment: Thanks Chirag, But unfortunately I can't use display:block as it is going to impact my whole layout. Basically in table there are multiple tbody and need to use table-row-group.

Comment: @Mayank I've tried your demo in FireFox, looks like that kind of effect is not really impressive and also can be achieved easily with a box-shadow style applied on the `td` elements, check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/w4p5L/12/

Comment: thanks, but this fix only provides shadow in td, not on whole tr and a gap is clearly visible, which we don't want.

Comment: @Mayank as I said, what the demo I posted looks almostly exactly to what FireFox renders your demo.

Comment: @KingKing there is a small tweak in it. In FF, we can see shadow under whole tr, but by applying shadow on td means showing shadow under td only.

Comment: @Mayank I did not look into the effect carefully, looks like it's not easy to achieve the exact effect, I've just tried playing with pseudo-elements hack however it's not really good, it may be acceptable (depending on your requirement) http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/w4p5L/16/ Anyway I have to say that table is a hard-to-style element, it's almost because of bug in how the browsers implement their CSS features. It's a pity that we can't play with pseudo-elements on the `tbody`, it's buggy indeed. So if each group has more than 1 row, the whole group is hardly styled.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `div` within the `th` or `tr` tag as a workaround and assign a `box-shadow` to the div instead. I've implemented this in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w4p5L/11/) to the first `th` element.

Comment: Thanks chirag. It works fine, but again it's a shadow under the div only not on whole row. which is the actual need for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tbody {

 -webkit-box-shadow:  5px 5px 3px green;
 -moz-box-shadow:  5px 5px 3px green;
  box-shadow:  5px 5px 3px green;
  display: block
```

}

It works.

Comment: as I mentioned earlier, I can't use display:block, it breaks my whole layout. you can see it here. http://jsfiddle.net/w4p5L/15/